# Get the latest updated Variable in mutliple C files

Tags: c

I have a value that get updated in two c files,
for instance
I have a counter variable that get incremented in one file counterPlus.c
and in the other file it get decremented counterMinus.c.
I want to write a logic in such a way that, if counter = 5 and counter get incremented in counterPlus.c by two values, counter is read as counter = 7  in counterMinus.c Similarly If counter gets decremented by 1 in counterMinus.c, counterPlus.c  reads it as 6.

One approach is to use extern variable but is there any other way

Comment: Objects can be referred to by their names or by their addresses. For the name to be known in multiple source files (translation units, unless you kludge compilation of multiple source files together, which is bad practice), the name must have external linkage. For the address, but not the name, to be known in both source files, it could be passed to routines in those files. For example, at the start of program execution, `main` could call an initialization routine in each file, passing the address of a static object.

Comment: That said, this sounds like a novice attempt at program design, and you should ask a question with more information about your broader goal rather than focusing on this one method of solving it.

Comment: Is your program a single-threaded application? Otherwise you will have to pay attention to _concurrency_ (using OS locks). Please, provide some code. The solution may be easy (just passing pointer to the variable to be incremented/decremented instead of its value), but some reference code is required,

Answer (score 0):

Other than extern you can consider passing the variable from one file by pointer or reference to the functions using them, which is probably a more common pattern.  For this you need to share the signature of the function in the file with the variable which is commonly done through headers you include.